# How to route to generated Ex_Docs in Phoenix Framework

Tags: documentation, router, elixir, phoenix-framework

I used the ex_docs package to automatically generate documentation regarding my project modules in a Phoenix Framework project.
Then with `mix docs` I successfully created the doc folder at the root of the project.
However the contained files are full-fledged html files instead of templates.
How can I route to these files with the Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is generated as static HTML files. You can serve static files with phoenix from the `priv/static` directory, copy your files from `doc/` to the static directory.

You can find the configuration for the static file in your `endpoint.ex` file, see plug for documentation: http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html.

Comment: I moved it to the static directory. I also added it to the `endpoint.ex` at:
`only: ~w(css images js doc favicon.ico robots.txt)`
Yet nothing displays at localhost:4000/doc or localhost:4000/doc/index.html